# Trouble tracking recursive function

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I have this code which outputs:  10 5 16 8 4 2 11
However, I don't have any clue from where the 11 is coming from since when tracing i get the following:

```
H(10)
 H(5)
  1+H(16) //does this result in 17?
    H(8)
      H(4)
        H(2)
         H(1) -> returns 0
```

Moreover what happens to the (1) in 1+H(16) ?
Thus shouldnt my output of the n values be: 10 5 17 8 4 2 1

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int H ( int n ) {
  cout << " " << n<<" ";
  if ( n == 1 ) return 0;
  if ( n%2 != 0 ) return 1 + H ( 3*n + 1 );
  else return H ( n/2 );
} 

int main() {
//   for ( int i=0; ++i<=20; )
//     cout << H(i) << endl;
cout << H(10) << endl;
}
```

Comment: @tadman done my bad

Comment: You should be able to tear this problem apart by stepping through the program with a debugger and keeping an eye out for the unexpected.

Comment: Note: It's not an 11, it's two ones that don't have a whitespace between them. Try `cout << n << " ";`

Comment: I found `int H ( int n ) {
    cout << '#' << n << endl;
  int retval;
  if ( n == 1 ) retval = 0;
  else if ( n%2 != 0 ) retval = 1 + H ( 3*n + 1 );
  else retval = H ( n/2 );
  cout << " " << n << " " << retval << endl;
  return retval;
  
} 
` very informative

Comment: @MartinBonner that makes it much clearer but i cant understand from where we are getting the last two 1's

Comment: The last but one "1" comes from `cout << " " << n;`.  The final "1" comes from `cout << H(10) << endl;` in `main`.

Comment: @MartinBonner so the function basically return n which is the one coming from right 1+H(16)?

Comment: `H(10) = H(5) = 1 + H(16) = 1 + H(8) = 1 + H(4) = 1 + H(2) = 1 + H(1) = 1 + 0 = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the recursion, the function prints `1` then the stack pops everything out and the `main` prints the returned value `1` (0 is returned at the end of the recursion and only the call to H(5) adds one to the result), so `11` is printed.

Comment: So it adds 1 to the original value? or is it some indentation mistake because i was able to get 1 1 after adding a space

Comment: @Matcha_boy98 What do you mean? `H(10)=H(5)=1+H(16)=1+H(8)=1+H(4)=1+H(2)=1+H(1)=1+0=1`then you print `10 5 16 8 4 2 1 1` that's all.

Comment: @Matcha_boy98 Add a distinct prefix to each `cout` line (and preferably put on a separate line), and it will become much clearer.

Comment: How can i do that, do you mean with a prefix to indent the lines?

Comment: @Matcha_boy98 Take Martin's proposal as an exercise! How to generate the output you suggested in the question?